# Where is Yao's original proof that distinguishers imply next-bit-predictors?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, pseudorandomness, pseudorandom-generators

In the theory of pseudorandomness, there is a well-known lemma that says roughly the following. Let $X$ be a probability distribution over $\{0, 1\}^n$. Suppose there is an efficient algorithm that distinguishes $X$ from the uniform distribution with advantage $\varepsilon$. Then there is an efficient algorithm that correctly predicts the $i$th bit of $X$ with probability $1/2 + \varepsilon / n$ given the first $i - 1$ bits of $X$, for some $i \in [n]$.

The lemma is typically attributed to Yao, with a citation to the paper ["Theory and Application of Trapdoor Functions" (FOCS 1982)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4568378). For example, in the journal version of Blum and Micali's paper ["How to Generate Cryptographically Strong Sequences of Pseudorandom Bits" (SICOMP 1984)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0213053), they give a perfectly clear statement of (one version of) this lemma and attribute it to Yao.

But looking through Yao's paper, I am struggling to find the proof or even the statement of the lemma. In Section 2.3, Yao does briefly discuss the distinction between unpredictability and indistinguishability from the uniform distribution, but I can't find the generic reduction between the two notions of pseudorandomness in his paper.

Does the lemma somehow follow from some of the analysis in Yao's paper? Is there a "full version" of his paper with more details? What is the history of this lemma and its proof?

Comment: There is a running joke about how a lot of Andrew Yao's attributions are in person, at lectures, rather than in paper. Perhaps this is another example.